# Connectivity of the group of invertible elements of $C(S^{2})\otimes A$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

For what type of  $C^{*}$  algebras  $A$, the group of  invertible elements  of  $C(S^{2}) \otimes A$ is a  connected group?

All finite dimensional $A$ satisfy this property.

> Is it true to say that $A$ satisfy the above property if and only if the group of  invertible elements of  $A$ is connected?

Comment: You can generally replace "invertible" with "unitary" up to homotopy when working with C* algebras, so by Bott periodicity I think you just want to look at $K_1(A)$.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I think that the following two, are not equivalent: 1.unitary group of A is  connected.  2. $K_{1}(A)$ is trivial, right?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but isn't it the case that for a Banach algebra $B$, $GL(B)$ is connected iff it is path-connected?  I think it's then clear that $GL(C(S^2)]\otimes A)) = C(S^2, GL(A))$ is path-connected iff $GL(A)$ is?

Comment: @user75274  Is it obvious that the connected  component of GL(A) has laways trivial second homotopy?

Comment: @Ali: If A is stabilized by the compact Operators, i.e. $A=(B \otimes K)^+$, then the answer is true if and only if $K_1(C(S^2) \otimes A)=0$. Bott periodicity Needs $C(R^2)$ instead of $C(S^2)$.